# Application.StartupPath en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy con una aplicación en c# (estoy empezando a aprender) y pensaba que este comando (`Application.StartupPath`) era para coger la raíz del proyecto, que es:

```
"E:\Proyectos\cs\App\CruceroSingleApp\CruceroSingleApp\"
```

que es el directorio en el cual estoy trabajando, pero este comando me coge como raíz del proyecto:

```
"E:\Proyectos\CS\App\CruceroSingleApp\CruceroSingleApp\bin\Debug\"
```

con, lo cual, me está dando error al intentar coger imágenes del directorio.

¿A qué es debido esto y como lo soluciono?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el directorio donde se encuentra tu proyecto lo puedse obtener de esta forma, primeramente obteniendo el directorio de trabajo (usando  `Environment.CurrentDirectory`) y usando este para posteriormente obtener el directorio de tu proyecto:

```
string workingDirectory =  Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string projectDirectory = Directory.GetParent(workingDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName;
```

el valor de `projectDirectory`  sería:

```
E:\Proyectos\cs\App\CruceroSingleApp\CruceroSingleApp
```